# Spark scala UDF complains NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: scala, apache-spark, databricks, user-defined-functions, databricks-sql

I am trying to write a simple spark UDF like this. When I test it in databricks notebook on a spark version `10.4.x-scala2.12`. The same code works just fine. When I run this in a packaged jar and submit to databricks on same spark version it results in an exception like this,

Exception: at `spark.sql(sql_stat).show(false)`

```
Job aborted due to stage failure.
Caused by: NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.test.TestClass$
:
:
at com.test.TestClass$.$anonfun$main$5(TestClass.scala:13)
```

Code:

```
    object Test{
     def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

        val udf_lambda =(id: Int) => {
          if (id%2==0)
            "group A"
          else
            "group B"
        }
    
        spark.udf.register("udf_lambda", udf_lambda)
        val sql_stat = "select udf_lambda(id) as idv2 from hive_table"
        spark.sql(sql_stat).show(false)
    }
  }
```

Any ideas on why this might be or how to troubleshoot it? I have the jar working just fine when i change the query to one without UDF. Simple query like `select id as idv2 from hive_table` just displays data form table. It

Comment: Can you check that the class `com.test.TestClass$` present in the packaged jar?

Comment: Try to place the UDF `udf_lambda` outside the main method

Comment: @DmytroMitin It is, and i know that is not the problem because as I mentioned in my question if i just update the query it works fine.

Comment: @RaphaelRoth I will try that out and update how that goes. But what can be the possible reason behind putting it outside main method may work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Method `udf_lambda` needs to be in a place where it can be serialized. The easiest way to do so is by placing it directly in an object.

```scala
object Test{
     val udf_lambda =(id: Int) => {
       if (id%2==0)
         "group A"
        else
           "group B"
     }

     def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {    
        spark.udf.register("udf_lambda", udf_lambda)
        val sql_stat = "select udf_lambda(id) as idv2 from hive_table"
        spark.sql(sql_stat).show(false)
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. 
But my code is still failing even after moving the lambda outside of the main method, with the same exception not sure why.

Comment: Sorry trying out few combination I confused myself it actually worked finally.